# Create a zip with ZipArchive getting files from s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

right now I am creating the ZIP in this way, with the PDF files that are in the Storage 'invoices'. My goal is to move all these local files to the amazon s3 server. At the time of removing a file I have only had no problem, but at the time of generating the zip yes. How can I solve that? Thanks.

```
$pdfs = $request->get('check');

$public_dir = storage_path();

if (is_array($pdfs)) {
    $zipname = "facturas" . time() . ".zip";
    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($public_dir . '/app/invoices/' . $zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        foreach ($pdfs as $pdf) {
            $zip->addFile(storage_path('app/invoices/' . $pdf), $pdf);
        }
    }

    $zip->close();

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
    );
    $filetopath = $public_dir . '/app/invoices/' . $zipname;
    if (file_exists($filetopath)) {
        return response()->download($filetopath, $zipname, $headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will help if you tell us precisely what the problem is. All we know is there is some sort of problem, but we don't know what it is. Please give a more specific, detailed description of the problem - see [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: @ADyson 

Hi, sorry. The problem is that when I made the ZIP "open" it was saved in the Storage invoices, and then from there it was projected to be downloaded. The thing is, I don't know how to do it with s3.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not really clear what you mean, or what it is you actually want to do. Are you asking how to put files which are stored on S3 into your zip file? Or, you want to host the zip file on S3 and be able to add things to it whilst it's stored there?

Comment: Both. Get the files from s3 to save them in the ZIP and save this ZIP in s3

@ADyson

Comment: You would need to build the zip locally on the PHP server (you'd have to download the files you need from s3 and then include them in the zip), and then upload it to S3. Unless there is a way to map the S3 storage as a local drive of course, but I don't know if that's possible, primarily S3 is intended as a backup or archive storage. In more complex (and expensive) scenarios you can use it for more real-time stuff. BTW I assume you've discovered the AWS SDK for PHP? https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/?nc=hl&pg=gs&p=s3